# How to destroy the fragment on Swipe?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am implementing the Tab View fragment something similar to [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

I have two tab. In first tab i play the music and when i swipe to second tab the music should stop. I have implemented something similar to this:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onDestroyView()` will not be called when you swipe, and destroying `fragment` to stop music sounds weird :D.

What you can do is you can implement `addOnPageChangeListener()` to `ViewPager` in your `Activity` and in its `onPageSelected()` method, you can get reference to `Tab` that contains the `MediaPlayer` and there you can `release` it